# thmtools: Spacing between boxes and text

Tags: spacing, thmtools

Using the package [thmtools](https://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) how can I make the spacing box-box, text-box, and box-text all the same? The space box-text and text-box is not the same. And the space box-box is in general larger (I assume the extra space of each box is added), which creates unnecessary space when multiple boxes are consecutive.
[image]

This is all the code I used:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%Packages%%

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[usenames,svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}


%%Thmtools%%

%Theorem style
\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries, 
    bodyfont=\itshape, 
    mdframed={
        linewidth=0.5pt, 
        nobreak=true, 
        innerbottommargin=7pt
    }
    ]{theoremstyle}

\declaretheorem[
    style=theoremstyle, 
    name=Theorem, 
    numbered=no
    ]{theorem]

\begin{document}


\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

This is some text.

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I think there a `\baselineskip` below the box. Could you try `skipabove=\baselineskip,` option for `mdframed`

Comment: @Tom I think you are right. If you do this, the space text-box and box-text are more equal. But the space box-box now is even larger. And by the way, the command skipbelow inside mdframed doesn't seem to work (skipabove works fine), I don't know why.

Comment: @Croqueta I am not sure what cause that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since mdframed is not actively maintained, I suggest you use [`tcolorbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox). The `\tcolorboxenvironment` command can wrap any environment with a tcolorbox with custom options.

```
\documentclass{article}

%%Packages%%

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%%Thmtools%%

%Theorem style
\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries, 
    bodyfont=\itshape, 
    ]{theoremstyle}

\declaretheorem[
    style=theoremstyle, 
    name=Theorem, 
    numbered=no,
    ]{theorem}

\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{
  colback=white,
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0.5pt,
  left=0.3cm,
  right=0.3cm,
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

This is some text.

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: theorem boxes]